# MySQL ALTER column to last position in table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-schema, alter-table

I'm working with a client who wants each table in a large database to have history data on each record, and for aesthetic appeal, wants these columns to be at the end of each table. For example:

**Table Name**

---

- Primary keys
- Data Columns
- History Columns

---

So my question is, is there an SQL command to move a column to the end of a table? I would prefer to write a Stored Procedure to move each history column to the last position in a predetermined order, but the only commands MySQL seems to have is FIRST and AFTER, no LAST option.

Is there an easy solution to this problem besides querying the information_schema tables for the column with the highest ordinal position, and moving it AFTER it?

**EDIT**

My current solution is to find the bottom-most row with the following:

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_name = tableName AND table_schema = currentSchema
    AND ordinal_position IN 
    (SELECT max(ordinal_position) FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_name = tableName AND table_schema = currentSchema
        AND column_name <> 'first_history_column'
        GROUP BY table_name);
```

And then order them accordingly as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName MODIFY 'first_history_column' AFTER column_name;
ALTER TABLE tableName MODIFY 'second_history_column' AFTER 'first_history_column';
etc...
```

Is there a faster way than this current solution?

Comment: Any reason the table has to be that way rather than any query returning the columns in that order or providing a view to do that?

Comment: This is a rabbit hole that you'll never emerge from. The only way is to query and save the data, drop the table, re-create the table with the new column order, and copy the old data back in. Give the client views with the columns in their desired order. You'll be doing the client a favor.

Comment: I agree, a customized view would be the best solution for this scenario, but it is also possible that the aesthetically sensitive client would like to access the DB on admin level.

Comment: The Client will be the IT Director and will access the database as an admin, but more importantly the GUI tools they use in design meetings pull the column names in order. The main issue is that new columns get missed/ignored in design when they are underneath several history columns which are expected to be the 'end' of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move a column, you have to duplicate it.

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD history_new VARCHAR(60)
```

will insert a new column at the end of the table.

```
UPDATE test SET history_new=history_old
```

will copy the values from the old column to the new column. And

```
ALTER TABLE test DROP history_old
```

will remove the old column.

**EDIT**

Just to give one alternative I didn't think of before:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD dummy TINYINT(1)
```

to insert a dummy column at the end of the table, just because you know the name.

```
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY first_history_column AFTER dummy
ALTER TABLE test DROP dummy
```

Then you move your history column(s) after the dummy and delete it. So it's just 3 ALTER TABLES and no UPDATE.

Comment: Followed by _ALTER TABLE test CHANGE history_new history_old VARCHAR(60)_ to retain the column name

Comment: This is a solution, but I'm worried it would be an expensive one across thousands of tables and trillions of records of data. How much more expensive would these 4 operations be than a single ALTER TABLE statement?

Comment: If it was millions of rows, potentially hours, and it might lock all the rows in the db so you cant update or query. Your database admin would say no. Your alter table statement would always take an instant.

Comment: I added another idea. But I think your current solution is still faster.

Comment: Nice, that is much better. This would still incur the overhead of creating a column which still could not be an option in some cases.

Comment: I do like your second idea, if my first implementation doesn't cut it I'll give yours a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can search for your history columns, why dont you make every column that isnt a history column first in the table

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = tableName AND table_schema = currentSchema
AND column_name NOT LIKE '%history%' and table_name = tableName
```

And then make the primary keys first in the table.

```
SELECT k.COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.table_constraints t
LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage k
USING(constraint_name,table_schema,table_name)
WHERE t.constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY' and table_name = tableName
```